# Having issue in making jquery plugin with default options

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I have following code.

```
(function ($) {
    var Obj = {
        init: function (options, elem) {
            this.elem = elem;
            this.$elem = $(elem);
            this.url = 'http://example.com/api/public/v1.0/page.json';

            if (typeof options === 'string') {
                this.search = options;
            } else {
                this.search = options.search;
                this.options = $.extend({}, $.fn.jPlugin.options, options);
                console.log(self.options);
            }
        }
    };

    $.fn.jPlugin = function (options) {
        console.log(options);
        return this.each(function () {
            var obj = Object.create(Obj);
            obj.init(options, this);
        });
    };

    $.fn.jPlugin.options = {
        search: 'happy'
    };
})(jQuery);
```

When I call above plugin like `$('.element').jPlugin({ search: smile })` i.e. with options then it does log `smile` but when I call it without options `$('.element').jPlugin()` then it does not get the default options. Why and what am I doing wrong in this code?

Comment: You havn't followed the correct structure of writing a plugin. [visit here](http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/) please go through this site.

Answer (score 0):

You need to extend the default options then pass in the new object:

```
$.fn.jPlugin = function(options) {
  options = $.exend({}, $.fn.jPlugin.options, options || {});
  console.log(options)
}
```

The extend static method will copy the defaults to a new blank object, and then overwrite or add any properties on the new object with the properties from the passed in options. If nothing was passed in it will try to apply an empty object to the new options object, which will not do anything.

**edit**

I answered that too fast, you actually have a couple things wrong see this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7FrB3/ for a working answer.

basically you need to make sure you're not passing around an undefined option. So I make sure options will always be either the config object or a blank object. You were also logging 'self.options' which isn't defined. I think you meant 'this.options'